# Why does my image not show when wrapped in an Animated.View?

Tags: react-native

I am new to programming and my task is to animate the height of my image on scroll. i.e. decrease height on scroll down and increase height to original when scrolling up. However, following the React Native documentation on Animated, I replaced Text component with my Image and I'm unable to get the image showing. It shows when I don't wrap it in <Animated.View>, can anyone explain why and tell me how to fix? Thank you.

This is my current code just trying to do the sample fade animation before I try to animate height and running into issues getting the TopImage component showing:

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import TopImage from '../components/TopImage';
import GroceryList from '../components/GroceryList';


const App = () => {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const styles = createStyleSheet();

  const fadeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const fadeIn = () => {
    Animated.timing(fadeAnim, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 5000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };

  const fadeOut = () => {
    Animated.timing(fadeAnim, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 3000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.View
        style={
          {
            // Bind opacity to animated value
            opacity: fadeAnim,
          },
        }>
        <TopImage />
      </Animated.View>
      <ScrollView
        style={styles.scrollContainer}
        onScrollBeginDrag={() => fadeIn()}>
        <GroceryList />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

const createStyleSheet = () => {
  const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();

  return StyleSheet.create({
    container: { flex: 1 },
    scrollContainer: { paddingTop: headerHeight + 100 },
  });
};

export default App;
```

and this is the code for my TopImage component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const topImage = require('../images/top.png');

const TopImage = () => {
  const styles = createStyleSheet();
  return <Image source={topImage} style={styles.image} />;
};

const createStyleSheet = () => {
  return StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
      position: 'absolute',
      width: '100%',
      height: '50%',
    },
  });
};
export default TopImage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not showing is because your image is 'absolute' positioned and as such, the outer container (Animated.View) has no height.

If you apply a height to the Animated.View like below. You'll see that the opacity is actually working, you just couldn't see it before because the Animated.View was 0 pixels tall.

```
<Animated.View
    style={
      {
        // Bind opacity to animated value
        opacity: fadeAnim,
        height: 300,
      }, 
    }>
  <TopImage />
</Animated.View>
```

Alternatively you could make the image position relative, height 0 and animate it to the correct size.